# Method to Find ArrayList Index to Where the Object Will be Added

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` that is being filled with customer information using a `Customer` class. In my `addCustomerRecord` method, I am calling `findAddIndex` within the `addCustomerRecord` method so the data entered will be sorted prior to displaying the data. Here is my code and do not mind the `fileWhatever` method, I don't use it.

```
public class CustomerDemo
{
    //arrayList of customer objects
    public static ArrayList<Customer> customerAL = new ArrayList<>();



    public static void main (String[] args)
    {        
        //to hold menu choice
        String menuChoice = "";

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("To add a record press 'A': \n"
                + "to display all records press 'D': \n"
                + "to exit press 'Q': \n");

        //loop priming read
        menuChoice = kb.nextLine();

        //make input case insensitive
        menuChoice = menuChoice.toLowerCase();


        do
        {
            if(menuChoice.equals("a"))
                addCustomerRecord(kb);
            else if(menuChoice.equals("d"))
            {
                displayCustomerRecords();
            }
            else if(menuChoice.equals("q"))
            {
                System.out.println("Program exiting..");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("incorrect entry. Please re-enter a valid entry: \n");
                menuChoice = kb.nextLine();
                menuChoice = menuChoice.toLowerCase();
            }

            System.out.println("To add a record press 'A': \n"
                    + "to display all records press 'D': \n"
                    + "to exit press 'Q': \n");
            menuChoice = kb.nextLine();
            menuChoice = menuChoice.toLowerCase();
        }while(menuChoice.equals("a") || menuChoice.equals("d") || menuChoice.equals("q"));


        kb.close();
    }

   /*     public static void displayCustomerRecords()
    {
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < customerAL.size(); ++i)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-15s", customerAL.get(i).getLastName());
            System.out.printf("%-15s", customerAL.get(i).getFirstName());
            System.out.printf("%-6s", customerAL.get(i).getCustID());
            System.out.printf("%15s\n", customerAL.get(i).getPhoneNumber());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    /**
     * prompts to enter customer data and mutator methods called 
     * with a Scanner object passed as an argument to set data
     * @param location index position of where the element will be added. 
     * @param kb a Scanner object to accept input
     */

    public static void addCustomerRecord(Scanner kb)
    {

        Customer currentCustomerMemoryAddress = new Customer();

        System.out.println("Enter first name: \n");
        String fName = kb.nextLine();
        currentCustomerMemoryAddress.setFirstName(fName);

        System.out.println("Enter last name: \n");
        String lName = kb.nextLine();
        currentCustomerMemoryAddress.setLastName(lName);

        System.out.println("Enter customer phone number: \n");
        String pNum = kb.nextLine();
        currentCustomerMemoryAddress.setPhoneNumber(pNum);

        System.out.println("Enter customer ID number: \n");
        String ID = kb.nextLine();
        currentCustomerMemoryAddress.setCustID(ID);

        int addLocation = findAddLocation(currentCustomerMemoryAddress);

        customerAL.add(addLocation, currentCustomerMemoryAddress);

        currentCustomerMemoryAddress = null;
    }

    public static int findAddLocation(Customer cust)
    {
        int location = 0;

        if(!customerAL.isEmpty())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < customerAL.size(); i++)
            {
                //Stumped here
            }
        }
        else
            return location;
        return location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are reinventing the wheel here William

Replace your code for `displayCustomerRecords` with this:

```
public static void displayCustomerRecords()
    {
        System.out.println();
        customerAL.stream().map(c -> String.format("%-15s%-15s%-6s%15s\n",
                c.getLastName(), c.getFirstName(), c.getCustID(), c.getPhoneNumber()))
                .sorted()
                .forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Update**

Taking into account your comment you can replace your `findAddLocation`method by the following:

```
private static Comparator<Customer> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Customer::getLastName)
                .thenComparing(Customer::getFirstName)
                .thenComparing(Customer::getCustID)
                .thenComparing(Customer::getPhoneNumber);


public static int findAddLocation(Customer cust)
{

    int location = 0;

    if(!customerAL.isEmpty())
    {
        for(Customer customerInList : customerAL)
        {
            if(comparator.compare(customerInList, cust) > 0) {
                break;
            }
            location++;
        }
    }
    return location;
}
```

We are traversing the array using Java's enhanced for-loop and comparing the objects using a Java 8 declared comparator (which I believe is the key to this assignment).

It would be a good idea if you could look into the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and implement it in your `Customer` class. That way you could simply do a simple call to `customerInList.compareTo(cust)` to compare both objects.

As already stated, this is **not** a good practice and shouldn't be used in production code.

Comment: I believe my professor wanted the class to reinvent the wheel. The assignment specs say, "Call the findAddLocation method from the addCustomerRecord method so that the arrayList will be in order upon display." The findAddLocation method is suppose to find the correct index within the ArrayList to place the object based on the last name of the customer. @MarcNuri

Comment: I've added another approach to solve your problem. Please consider looking into Comparator and Comparable in Java.